# How match chrome extension permission to current chrome version?

Tags: google-chrome, permissions, google-chrome-extension

I have extension that currently asks for permission for "tabs", in the new version of my extension I want to use "webRequest" and "webRequestBlocking".
I know that if an old chrome (version < 17) will try to install my extension (with the new webRequest permissions) it won't install the extension. 
How can I use the permission only for chrome version that supports the permission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use the `minimum_chrome_version` field in the `manifest.json`. This will unfortunately keep all older versions of Chrome from updating but there isn't much else you can do.

https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#minimum_chrome_version

---

Update: Optional permissions were added in version 16. You can use these ask for permission if the APIs are supported. It will be more work to implement even though 90+% of Chrome installs will be on version 17+ by the end of the month.

https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/permissions.html

Comment: But I still want to support old version of chrome, they won't have the new feature which is good.. but I don't want to lose those users..

Comment: You can also use optional permissions. I just updated my answer to include that.